# filling one dimension of two-dimensional array with other array

Tags: python, arrays, list-comprehension

i have two lists:

```
a=[[10, 0], [12,1], [13, 8], [2, -3]]
b=[1, 2, -30, 404]
```

i'd like to replace the `a[*][1]` values with the ones from `b`, so that my result looks like:

```
[[10, 1], [12, 2], [13, -30], [2, 404]]
```

an obvious way (for me, being really a *C*-programmer) would be something like:

```
for i in range(len(a)):
   a[i][1]=b[i]
```

but somehow this feels not very pythonic.

what how would i do that in a pythonic way?

additionally, the `b`-list could have more or less elements than `a`. if there are less, the remaining elements in `a` should stay unchanged.

```
a=[[10, 0], [12,1], [13, 8], [2, -3]]
b=[10, 20]

result=[[10, 10], [12,20], [13, 8], [2, -3]]
```

if they are more, i'd like to add new entries with a default first element (e.g. `None`)

```
a=[[10, 0], [12,1]]
b=[100, 200, -30, 404]

result=[[10, 100], [12,200], [None, -30], [None, 404]]
```

can this be acchieved with list-comprehensions?

Comment: It would help me to understand why you think your solution is unpythonic. Because as I said in my answer, I don't think it is – a simple list comprehension is a beautiful thing, but *Sparse is better than dense* is more pythonic.

Comment: @kojiro `for(i=0; i<len(); i++)` always gives me the impression i'm thinking too much in *C*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`enumerate` is generally accepted as a pythonic alternative to looping over the range of list indices. Other than that, there's really nothing unpythonic about your solution.

```
for i, v in enumerate(b):
  try:
    a[i][1] = v
  except IndexError:
    a.append([None, v])
```

or, using iterators to avoid multiple try/catch triggers:

```
bnumer = enumerate(b)
for i, v in bnumer:
  try:
    a[i][1] = v
  except IndexError:
    break

# extend the list with the remaining default values from b
a.extend([None,v] for v in bnumer)
```

Comment: i like that (esp. the non-optimized first solution); but `a[i]=[None, v]` will bail out with an IndexError; `a[i]+=[[None, v]]`

Comment: while i like @hcwhsa's answer most for the simple case (with both lists of equal length), this solution seems to be the most readable for both cases.

Answer (score 2):

Use `zip` and list comprehension:

```
>>> a[:] = [[x, z] for (x, y), z   in zip(a, b)]
>>> a
[[10, 1], [12, 2], [13, -30], [2, 404]]
```

For the cases with unequal length lists you can use `iterools.izip_longest`:

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> a = [[10, 0], [12,1], [13, 8], [2, -3]]
>>> b = [10, 20]
>>> sen = object()
#len(a) > len(b)
>>> a[:] = [[x, y if z is sen else z]
                          for (x, y), z in izip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=sen)]
>>> a
[[10, 10], [12, 20], [13, 8], [2, -3]]

>>> a = [[10, 0], [12,1]]
>>> b = [100, 200, -30, 404]
#len(b) > len(a)
>>> a[:] = [[None if x is sen else x , z] 
                          for (x, y), z in izip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=[sen]*2)]
>>> a
[[10, 100], [12, 200], [None, -30], [None, 404]]
```

---

Use a `generator function`, if you think that the list comprehensions are too unreadable:

```
def solve(a, b):
    sen = object()
    if len(a) == len(b):
        for (x, y), z in zip(a, b):
            yield [x, z]
    elif len(a) > len(b):
        for (x, y), z in izip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=sen):
            yield [x, y if z is sen else z]
    else:
        for (x, y), z in izip_longest(a, b, fillvalue=[sen]*2):
            yield [None if x is sen else x , z]
```

**Demo:**

```
>>> list(solve([[10, 0], [12,1], [13, 8], [2, -3]], [1, 2, -30, 404]))
[[10, 1], [12, 2], [13, -30], [2, 404]]

>>> list(solve([[10, 0], [12,1], [13, 8], [2, -3]], [10, 20]))
[[10, 10], [12, 20], [13, 8], [2, -3]]

>>> list(solve([[10, 0], [12,1]], [100, 200, -30, 404]))
[[10, 100], [12, 200], [None, -30], [None, 404]]
```

Comment: Cute, but how is it actually *better* than a simple loop?

Comment: @kojiro List comprehension and no indexes.

Comment: We can get into an argument about what *pythonic* means, but I think this violates lines 5, 9, 15 and possibly 19 of `python -m this | cat -n`

Answer (score 1):

Try this, using list comprehensions:

```
if len(a) > len(b):
    result = [[e[0], b[i]] if i < len(b) else e for i, e in enumerate(a)]
else:
    result = [[a[i][0], e] if i < len(a) else [None, e] for i, e in enumerate(b)]
```

The above takes into consideration the three cases described in the question, whether it's more pythonic or not it's up to you to judge - but it produces *correct* results, and that's what matters most.